# Bash using curl to check headers and mailing me if there are any errors

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the headers of few web sites with curl , and send mail when i get errors like 404,403,500,503 but i keep getting this error

Error:

```
line 7: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

Code:

```
# !/bin/sh

NOW=$(date +"%H:%M_%m-%d-%Y")

web() {
    res=$(curl -I -s "$1" -o test/"$1_log_$NOW" | grep HTTP/1.1 | awk {'print $2'})
    if [ $res -eq 500 ]
    then
      echo "Error $res on $1" |mail -s "Error $res at $1 "mail@something.com

    fi
}
```

I manage to do what i wanted but i changed a lot of the script :

```
#!/bin/sh

NOW=$(date +"%H:%M_%m-%d-%Y")

web() {

res=$(curl -I -s $1  | grep HTTP/1.1 | awk {'print $2'})
if [[ "$res" == 500 ||"$res" == 403 || "$res" == 404 ||"$res" == 503 ]]
then
  echo "Error $res on $1" |mail -s "Error $res at $1 " somethng@domain.com


fi
echo "$res" > /home/user/test/"$1_log_$NOW"

}
web domain1.com
```

Comment: Consider what happens in your script if `$res` is empty.

Comment: probably $res has space separated strings, and that's resulting in the error. Try using "$res".

Comment: You will always end up with empty res. Try to fix these 3 things. You are sending output of curl to a file "-o" option. grep is trying to read from stdin which is empty because curl sends output to a file. grep is looking for HTTP/1.1, some servers may return HTTP/1.0.

Comment: Thank you for the info guys, i changed some parts of the code but i still do not get any emails about the errors. I know i am lame but i wanted to try this : if [[ "$res" = "500","503","403","404" ]]

Comment: Is the mailing part working? Try to add a touch "/tmp/had.error" after the "then" and check if the script reachs the place... And/or give an example for one of your test websites, in order for better "debuging"

Comment: The whole thing was working until i wanted the output to be saved in a file and to match more than one error - 500 ,503 , 404, 403 . I dont know how to match my result to  more than one error code ><.